# Having problems with scipy.integrate.solve_ivp

Tags: python, solver, differential-equations, scipy-optimize, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to use scipy.integrate.solve_ivp to calculate the solutions to newton's gravitation equation for my n body simulation, however I am confused how the function is passed into solve_ivp. I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

G = 6.67408e-11

m_sun = 1988500e24
m_jupiter = 1898.13e24
m_earth = 5.97219e24

au = 149597870.700e3
v_factor = 1731460
year = 31557600.e0

init_s = np.array([-6.534087946884256E-03*au, 6.100454846284101E-03*au, 1.019968145073305E-04*au, -6.938967653087248E-06*v_factor, -5.599052606952444E-06*v_factor, 2.173251724105919E-07*v_factor])
init_j = np.array([2.932487231769548E+00*au, -4.163444383137574E+00*au, -4.833604407653648E-02*au, 6.076788230491844E-03*v_factor, 4.702729516645153E-03*v_factor, -1.554436340872727E-04*v_factor])

variables_s = init_s
variables_j = init_j

N = 2
tStart = 0e0
t_End = 25*year
Nt = 2000
dt = t_End/Nt
temp_end = dt
t=tStart
domain = (t, temp_end)

planetsinit = np.vstack((init_s, init_j))
planetspos = planetsinit[:,0:3] 
mass = np.vstack((1988500e24, 1898.13e24))

def weird_division(n, d):
    return n / d if d else 0

variables_save = np.zeros((N,6,Nt))
variables_save[:,:,0] = planetsinit

pos_s = planetspos[0] 
pos_j = planetspos[1] 

while t < t_End:
    t_index = int(weird_division(t, dt))

    for index in range(len(planetspos)):

        for otherindex in range(len(planetspos)):

            if index != otherindex:

                x1_p1, x2_p1, x3_p1 = planetsinit[index, 0:3]
                x1_p2, x2_p2, x3_p2 = planetsinit[otherindex, 0:3]
                m = mass[otherindex]

                def f_grav(t, y):
                    x1_p1, x2_p1, x3_p1, v1_p1, v2_p1, v3_p1 = y
                    x1_diff = x1_p1 - x1_p2
                    x2_diff = x2_p1 - x2_p2
                    x3_diff = x3_p1 - x3_p2
               
                    dydt = [v1_p1,
                            v2_p1,
                            v3_p1,
                            -(x1_diff)*G*m/((x1_diff)**2+(x2_diff)**2+(x3_diff)**2)**(3/2),
                            -(x2_diff)*G*m/((x1_diff)**2+(x2_diff)**2+(x3_diff)**2)**(3/2),
                            -(x3_diff)*G*m/((x1_diff)**2+(x2_diff)**2+(x3_diff)**2)**(3/2)]
                    return dydt

                solution = solve_ivp(fun=f_grav, t_span=domain, y0=planetsinit[index])

                planetsinit[index] = solution['y'][0:6, -1]
                variables_save[index,:,t_index] = solution['y'][0:6, -1]
                planetspos[index] = planetsinit[index][0:3] 

    t += dt
    temp_end += dt
    domain = (t,temp_end)

pos_s = variables_save[0,0:3,:]
pos_j = variables_save[1,0:3,:]

plt.plot(variables_save[0,0:3,:][0], variables_save[0,0:3,:][1])
plt.plot(variables_save[1,0:3,:][0], variables_save[1,0:3,:][1])
```

The code above works very nicely and produces a stable orbit. However when I calculate the acceleration outside the function and feed that through into the f_grav function, something goes wrong and produces an orbit which is no longer stable. However I am perplexed as I don't know why the data is different as to be it seems like that I have passed through the exactly same inputs. Which leads me to think that maybe its the way the the function f_grav is interpolated by the solve_ivp integrator? To calculate the acceleration outside all I do is change the following code in the loop to:

```
x1_p1, x2_p1, x3_p1 = planetsinit[index, 0:3]
x1_p2, x2_p2, x3_p2 = planetsinit[otherindex, 0:3]
m = mass[otherindex]

x1_diff = x1_p1 - x1_p2
x2_diff = x2_p1 - x2_p2
x3_diff = x3_p1 - x3_p2

ax = -(x1_diff)*G*m/((x1_diff)**2+(x2_diff)**2+(x3_diff)**2)**(3/2)
ay = -(x2_diff)*G*m/((x1_diff)**2+(x2_diff)**2+(x3_diff)**2)**(3/2)
az = -(x3_diff)*G*m/((x1_diff)**2+(x2_diff)**2+(x3_diff)**2)**(3/2)

def f_grav(t, y):
    x1_p1, x2_p1, x3_p1, v1_p1, v2_p1, v3_p1 = y
               
    dydt = [v1_p1,
            v2_p1,
            v3_p1,
            ax,
            ay,
            az]
    return dydt

solution = solve_ivp(fun=f_grav, t_span=domain, y0=planetsinit[index])

planetsinit[index] = solution['y'][0:6, -1]
variables_save[index,:,t_index] = solution['y'][0:6, -1]
planetspos[index] = planetsinit[index][0:3]
```

As I said I don't know why different orbits are produces which are shown below and any hints as to why or how to solve it would me much appreciated. To clarify why I can't use the working code as it is, as when more bodies are involved I aim to sum the accelerations contribution of all the other planets which isn't possible this way where the acceleration is calculated in the function itself.

Sorry for the large coding chunks but I did feel it was appropriate as then it could be run and the problem itself is clearer.

[image: Orbits plotted using code]

Both have the same time period, dt, however the orbit on the left is stable and the one on the right is not

Comment: You are not solving one 3-body problems, but 6 one-body problems. It is not surprising that you get strange results. You need to take the cumulative mutual gravity forces into account in every time step, using the recent position of all bodies.

Comment: Consult also similar topics in this category, the search "[orbital-mechanics] [python] body" (https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=[orbital-mechanics]+[python]+body) seems to give a good selection.

Comment: Not sure why you are saying that I am solving 6 one-body problems. I thought my code was calculating a 2 body problem. Although I do want to extend this code to an n body problem but don't know how.

Comment: You established 3 bodies. In the test case of 2 bodies, you would then solve 2 one-body problems. You just need to interpret what the function that you pass to `solve_ivp` actually computes. It is the gravitational force relative to the fixed initial position of the other body. Thus you get elliptical orbits around that fixed position, which contradicts the physics somewhat.

Comment: Ah after some thinking I finally understand what you are saying I think. Now I have implemented solve_ivp once and has all the planets needed within the function. For some reason I didn't think you could use solve ivp like that as y0 could only take 2D and I was thinking about stacking them horizontally. However what I now realise is that you can just make the 1D array as long as you like. Thank you very much for the comment I didn't realise I was using solve_ivp so inefficiently, much appreciated.

Comment: I also realise now that I was wasting the efficiency of solve_ivp by changing the domain every dt when it can itself cleverly change its own dt to produce what it deems are the best results.